# maven: package javafx.scene.media is not visible

Tags: java, maven, javafx, netbeans, media-player

initially i was trying to create cross platform executable from javafx project. Everything was working fine so i wanted to add audio in my project so i added `javafx-media` in `pom.xml` until i added javafx-media dependancy everything was good but now i'm getting error that `package javafx.scene.media is not visible` also it dosen't resolve Media class. How to resolve this?

FYI i'm using :
Project: Maven
Java: JDK 13
IDE: netbeans 13
Javafx: openjfx 11

Here is my project structure:

[image: Project Structure image]

Please let me know if you need more clarification.

***pom.xml***

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>HellojavaFxMaven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.mycompany.hellojavafxmaven.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for manual attach debugging -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run@debug -->
                        <id>debug</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=localhost:8000</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for automatic IDE debugging -->
                        <id>ide-debug</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address}</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for automatic IDE profiling -->
                        <id>ide-profile</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg1}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg2}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg3}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg4}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg5}</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

***App.java***

```
package com.mycompany.hellojavafxmaven;

import static java.lang.Math.random;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.effect.BlendMode;
import javafx.scene.effect.BoxBlur;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.CycleMethod;
import javafx.scene.paint.LinearGradient;
import javafx.scene.paint.Stop;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.StrokeType;
import javafx.util.Duration;


/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class App extends Application {

    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        Media m = new Media("");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600, Color.BLACK);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        Group circles = new Group();
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            Circle circle = new Circle(150, Color.web("white", 0.05));
            circle.setStrokeType(StrokeType.OUTSIDE);
            circle.setStroke(Color.web("white", 0.16));
            circle.setStrokeWidth(4);
            circles.getChildren().add(circle);
        }
        Rectangle colors = new Rectangle(scene.getWidth(), scene.getHeight(),
                new LinearGradient(0f, 1f, 1f, 0f, true, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE, new Stop[]{
                    new Stop(0, Color.web("#f8bd55")),
                    new Stop(0.14, Color.web("#c0fe56")),
                    new Stop(0.28, Color.web("#5dfbc1")),
                    new Stop(0.43, Color.web("#64c2f8")),
                    new Stop(0.57, Color.web("#be4af7")),
                    new Stop(0.71, Color.web("#ed5fc2")),
                    new Stop(0.85, Color.web("#ef504c")),
                    new Stop(1, Color.web("#f2660f")),}));
        colors.widthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());
        colors.heightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());
        Group blendModeGroup =
                new Group(new Group(new Rectangle(scene.getWidth(), scene.getHeight(),
                     Color.BLACK), circles), colors);
        colors.setBlendMode(BlendMode.OVERLAY);
        root.getChildren().add(blendModeGroup);      
        circles.setEffect(new BoxBlur(10, 10, 3));
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
        for (Node circle : circles.getChildren()) {
            timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, // set start position at 0
                    new KeyValue(circle.translateXProperty(), random() * 800),
                    new KeyValue(circle.translateYProperty(), random() * 600)),
                    new KeyFrame(new Duration(40000), // set end position at 40s
                    new KeyValue(circle.translateXProperty(), random() * 800),
                    new KeyValue(circle.translateYProperty(), random() * 600)));
        }
        // play 40s of animation
        timeline.play();
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

Comment: What does your `module-info.java` file look like?

Comment: You'll need to `import javafx.scene.media.Media;`.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks [Sedrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2423906/sedrick) for pointing it out. I have created maven javafx project in eclipse and inspect the `module-info.java` file and got the issue. so now i edited my `module-info.java`

```
module com.mycompany.hellojavafxmaven {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.media;
    exports com.mycompany.hellojavafxmaven;
}
```

just had to add one line `requires javafx.media;`.